# Gentilicios para oriundo San Pedro

Tags: diferencias-regionales, gentilicio

Estoy escribiendo y necesito hacer referencia a a una persona que vino de la ciudad de San Pedro del Ycuamandiyú, república del Paraguay

Consulté wikipedia y encuentro [sanpedrano/a](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Gentilicios_de_Paraguay#Departamento_de_San_Pedro) por un lado y en otra página encuentro [sampedrano/a](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Pedro_de_Ycuamandiy%C3%BA) (ver la el cuadro de wikidata)

Por lo que querría saber cómo se dice: **sanpedrano**, **sampedrano**, o **san pedrano** a alguien que es de San Pedro. Por lo que parece depende de la región y la historia, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna regla o algo con lo que uno pueda guiarse para construir los gentilicios?

Comment: particularmente estaba escribiendo sobre Paraguay, pero si estoy más interesado en saber si hay una regla para construir los gentilicios con palabras compuestas

Comment: "Sanpedrano" creo que iría contra las reglas de ortografía (`m` antes de `p`) y el gentilicio sería un único término (en "san pedrano" ese "san" es como un modificador, no parte de la palabra). Mira [esta lista](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/paises-y-capitales-con-sus-gentilicios) y compara los de San Cristóbal, San José, San Juan... Supongo que al gentilicio se le aplican las reglas de ortografía, pero no hay reglas para formar un gentilicio. Se forman un poco como de casualidad.

Comment: Asumo que te refieres a "Sanpedrano" con `n` y justamente por que no parecen haber reglas me preocupa que se ignore la regla de `m` antes de `p`

Comment: No sé si existirán pero no se me ocurre ningún gentilicio que no sea una sola palabra. Aquí hay una lista enorme: http://gentilicios.gratis.es/ y varios San Pedros, el de Paraguay es *sampedrano* pero hay *sampedrinos*, *sampetrinos* y otros.

Comment: clarifiqué la pregunta y di ejemplos de lo que encontré, particularmente la variante "san pedrano"  no la he oído pero para asegurar agregué a la pregunta, tampoco he oido ni leído nada sobre "sampedrino" con la terminación `pedrino`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo vivo relativamente cerca de un pueblo que se llama San Pedro del Pinatar. El gentilicio de las personas que allí viven es *pinatarenses*.
Nótese que se utiliza la segunda parte del nombre del pueblo, ya que es la que diferencia a este San Pedro de los otros cientos de San Pedro repartidos por el mundo hispano.

En tu caso, mencionas que la ciudad es San Pedro del Ycuamandiyú. Basta con buscar en Google para encontrar como primer resultado [la página de Wikipedia de la ciudad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Pedro_de_Ycuamandiy%C3%BA), donde se indica que el gentilicio es **sampedrano, sampedrana**.
En este caso, supongo que por no haber otros San Pedro cerca o por ser éste el más importante de la zona, se usa el nombre principal para formar el gentilicio.

No hay reglas establecidas para formar los gentilicios, ya que al final lo que prevalece es la manera en que los habitantes de cada pueblo se llamen a sí mismos o hayan sido llamados por sus vecinos a lo largo de los años.
Hay muchos ejemplos de sitios con nombres parecidos y gentilicios totalmente diferentes. Por ejemplo: los habitantes de España son *españoles*, pero los habitantes de Zaña (Perú), que se escribe y pronuncia casi igual, son *zañeros* y no ⓧ*zañoles*.

Lo que siempre se va a cumplir es que el gentilicio debe cumplir las normas de ortografía: ⓧ*sanpedrano* no tendría sentido.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta Walen, me queda claro que la formación de la palabra va a a depender de los lugareños, pero respecto a al uso de `n` o `m` me parece razonable lo que dices, solo que implica que la página de wikipedia de gentilicios de Paraguay está necesariamente mal, considerando que se refieren a la misma ciudad ?

Comment: todo aclarado entonces

Comment: O bien, la Florida, cuyo gentilicio puede ser *floridano* y *floridiano* (estado de EE.UU.), *floridense* (municipio uruguayo y estado de EE.UU.), *florideño* (municipio español / colombiano de Floridablanca/Florida Blanca,  municipio paraguayo de Villa Florida y municipio puertorricense, distrito peruano), *florideno* (municipio chileno)…